# Who is responsible for handling the logic of data-caching and in-memory storages?

Tags: caching, design-patterns, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

In a web service, when we put the responsibility of holding data to repositories, should we also put the responsibility of caching to them? Or it's responsibility of another part?

Also, what about the situations when we use  in-memory storages as a helper? for example when we counting number of posts' visits per day and saving them eventually in database, Should it handle on Repository?

Answer (score 3):

I think the `decorator` pattern works well for cached repository. The main idea is to separate caching and storage logic. So it will be correspond to Single responsibility principle.

[image]

What about statistic helper, it depends on the context. It can be:

- Also `decorator`, pass requests through itself, and implements `IRepository` interface:

`repo = new StatHelper(new CacheRepo(new DbRepo))`

- Separate tier with its own interface getting `IRepository` as a dependency.
- Logic can be implemented inside `CacheRepository` so as not to inflate the number of classes

Comment: There is still some logic to handle.
Sometimes we need the CacheR and DBR at the same time. 
Specially when we use in-memory storages as a helper, not a simple cache.

The question is, Who is responsible to handle this logic?

Comment: I think CacheRepository can handle the logic based on decided caching policy. There are multiple alternatives how read/write data to the cache e.g. read-through, write-through, write-around, write-behind, cache-aside.

Comment: Modified answer